# How to get correct sizes of tags in different string lengths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop a resize function for my tag container. But tags' total width varies due to character rendering, I guess. In the example below all containers have relatively the same total width of tags. But the difference in pixels is nearly 25.

I have 1 px `padding-left` in container properties. That's why I'm starting the variables from 1.
Also `margin` and `border` properties of the tags have 1px value. That's why I am getting the `.outerWidth()` inorder to have it all.

How can I get the precise sum of tags width as they appear in the screen? In other words, what is the right function to make `i == ii`?

```js
var  i = 1, ii = 1;
            $('#tagcontainer1').children("tag").each(function () {
                i += $(this).outerWidth()
            });
            $('#tagcontainer2').children("tag").each(function () {
                ii += $(this).outerWidth()
            });
            alert("#tagcontainer1 tags total width: "+i+" and #tagcontainer2 tags total width: "+ii);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1px 0px 0px 1px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 208px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden
}
tag {
  background: green;
  font: bold 16px/normal arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-image: none;
  color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="tagcontainer1"><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag >i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag >i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag>i</tag><tag >i</tag></div><div id="tagcontainer2"><tag>asd</tag><tag>asd</tag><tag>asd</tag><tag>asd</tag><tag>a</tag></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [include margin](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) to outerWidth calculations like:

```
$(this).outerWidth(true)
```

Comment: closer. 10px difference, still.

Comment: @Litestone I closer to what? what you expect? are you aware that you are calculating width of tags but not of container?

Comment: @Vladimirs you are right. It works fine only in Chrome. I think I am going to have IE and Firefox issues. Do you have any idea for a workaround?

Comment: @Litestone values differs because IE and chrome renders your html/css in different way - check outputs of individual tag http://jsfiddle.net/vvn951L8/ also even with eye I can see visual differences. To have same results you need to make cross-browser html/css - only than values will match.

Comment: @Vladimirs ok then. I'll continue with this.

Comment: @Litestone for testing purposes I added width:10px to tag and now IE and chrome results are matching - http://jsfiddle.net/wz51cmcL/1/